# How to write this query to receive SUM without breaking down by row using CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The subquery below gives me 15K rows with `NULL` values and money. Then I have to count the number of values only the ones that `NOT NULL`.
I know I can achieve that using CTE. But is any trick to use `Count` in this subquery and come up with a result of one cell? which is the count of `NOT NULL` values?
If yes, where would I inject `COUNT` or `SUM` in this query in order to get the result like that:
[image]

```
select      
                (Case when (Select COUNT(*) from tblQuoteDetails QD where QD.QuoteGUID = a.QuoteGUID) > 1 then
                              (SELECT Round(Sum(dbo.tblQuoteOptions.Premium),2)
                              FROM dbo.tblQuotes AS Q 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.lstQuoteStatus ON Q.QuoteStatusID = dbo.lstQuoteStatus.QuoteStatusID 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.tblQuoteOptions ON Q.QuoteGUID = dbo.tblQuoteOptions.QuoteGUID 
                              WHERE     (Q.ControlNo = a.ControlNo) 
                                    AND (Q.OriginalQuoteGUID IS NULL) 
                                    AND (dbo.tblQuoteOptions.Premium <> 0)
                                    AND (DATEDIFF(d,ISNULL(null, dbo.GetEffectiveDate(Q.QuoteGUID)), dbo.GetEffectiveDate(Q.QuoteGUID)) <= 0))
                        Else
                              (SELECT     Round(Avg(dbo.tblQuoteOptions.Premium),2)
                              FROM dbo.tblQuotes AS Q 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.lstQuoteStatus ON Q.QuoteStatusID = dbo.lstQuoteStatus.QuoteStatusID 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.tblQuoteOptions ON Q.QuoteGUID = dbo.tblQuoteOptions.QuoteGUID 
                              WHERE     (Q.ControlNo = a.ControlNo) 
                                    AND (Q.OriginalQuoteGUID IS NULL) 
                                    AND (dbo.tblQuoteOptions.Premium <> 0)
                                    AND (DATEDIFF(d,ISNULL(null, dbo.GetEffectiveDate(Q.QuoteGUID)), dbo.GetEffectiveDate(Q.QuoteGUID)) <= 0))
                       End) As QuotedPremium
                       FROM
       tblQuotes a 
       inner join  lstlines l on a.LineGUID = l.LineGUID
       where l.LineName = 'EARTHQUAKE' AND YEAR(EffectiveDate) = 2016
```

The result of above query:
[image]

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Comment: I added a pic above. Thanks

Comment: I just need to count cells that have` NOT NULL` value

Comment: Looking at that query using SELECT in the CASE WHEN and also in the THEN and then another join, I am thinking this entire query should be re-thought!  As your narrative is not very clear either perhaps you can attempt to include table schemas, sample data and desired out put and NOT as images!

Comment: is 1525 count of nulls..? can you explain little bit more..You may also check this link and spend some quality time to reframe  the question.Its worth ..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: try `;with cte as (your query) select count(that column name) from cte`

Comment: 1525 is the counts of `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query below, what you need to do is just use your code in a subquery.

```
select count(*) from(
select      
                (Case when (Select COUNT(*) from tblQuoteDetails QD where QD.QuoteGUID = a.QuoteGUID) > 1 then
                              (SELECT Round(Sum(dbo.tblQuoteOptions.Premium),2)
                              FROM dbo.tblQuotes AS Q 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.lstQuoteStatus ON Q.QuoteStatusID = dbo.lstQuoteStatus.QuoteStatusID 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.tblQuoteOptions ON Q.QuoteGUID = dbo.tblQuoteOptions.QuoteGUID 
                              WHERE     (Q.ControlNo = a.ControlNo) 
                                    AND (Q.OriginalQuoteGUID IS NULL) 
                                    AND (dbo.tblQuoteOptions.Premium <> 0)
                                    AND (DATEDIFF(d,ISNULL(null, dbo.GetEffectiveDate(Q.QuoteGUID)), dbo.GetEffectiveDate(Q.QuoteGUID)) <= 0))
                        Else
                              (SELECT     Round(Avg(dbo.tblQuoteOptions.Premium),2)
                              FROM dbo.tblQuotes AS Q 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.lstQuoteStatus ON Q.QuoteStatusID = dbo.lstQuoteStatus.QuoteStatusID 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.tblQuoteOptions ON Q.QuoteGUID = dbo.tblQuoteOptions.QuoteGUID 
                              WHERE     (Q.ControlNo = a.ControlNo) 
                                    AND (Q.OriginalQuoteGUID IS NULL) 
                                    AND (dbo.tblQuoteOptions.Premium <> 0)
                                    AND (DATEDIFF(d,ISNULL(null, dbo.GetEffectiveDate(Q.QuoteGUID)), dbo.GetEffectiveDate(Q.QuoteGUID)) <= 0))
                       End) As QuotedPremium
                       FROM
       tblQuotes a 
       inner join  lstlines l on a.LineGUID = l.LineGUID
       where l.LineName = 'EARTHQUAKE' AND YEAR(EffectiveDate) = 2016) as b
       where b.QuotedPremium is not null
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed.